# How to select all the columns that are null or empty with Doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have a large form for each "Participant". This is divided into several parts.
So I have my "Participant" table with several OneToOne relation for each party.

[Participant Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzNph.png)

I want to know if each part is filled, so count the number of empty fields.

I started working with a raw SQL query (which doesn't work).
I also cannot translate it into Doctrine language.

```
CONCAT(
    SELECT * FROM `db`.`participant` WHERE CONCAT(,
    (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(COLUMN_NAME)
        FROM `information_schema`.`COLUMNS`
        WHERE `TABLE_SCHEMA` = \'db\' AND
        `TABLE_NAME` = \'participant\'
        AND `IS_NULLABLE` = \'YES\'),
    ) IS NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Could you please add the error or some more info related to it. All info, code, database structure can help us to help you :)

Comment: Is there a way for each row to count the number of null values ​​in each column?

Comment: What does your Doctrine entity class for Participant look like? Can you add that to the question? And also, what is the purpose of counting the number of empty fields? I'm not sure what you're trying to achieve and if counting the number of empty fields is the best approach.

Comment: I added it. I want to display a progress in filling out the forms for each participant. I don't know if this is the best approach indeed.